# Reading first line from in-memory CSV file using io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv

I can successfully upload and access a CSV file using a Django form and loop through the rows in the file. However, the first row contains the column headers and these are somehow skipped when the code begins to read the file.

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():

        csvfile = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['file'], encoding="utf-8")

        logger.info('Position: {}'.format(csvfile.tell())) # <-- This returns 0

        for line in csvfile:

            logger.info('line: {}'.format(line)) # <-- The first iteration actually logs the second line in the CSV file.
```

What would cause the first call to the file in the `for` loop to return the second line in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with the uploaded CSV file. After opening up the test CSV file to scrub the data and re-saving it under a new name before posting, I was able to read the column header line from the scrubbed CSV file.

The original source CSV was an emailed CSV export from Excel. Opening the CSV in LibreOffice Calc and re-saving as a CSV file remove several hidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks file however I'm not sure why it is not working. You can post your sample CSV file or you can try with Python's CSV reader. It is a better library than io. See the example below.

Assuming your file looks like this.

```
workers,constant,age
w0,7.334,-1.406
w1,5.235,-4.936
w2,3.2225,-1.478
w3,0,0
```

this code should give you an idea or two:

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open('myclone.csv', 'rb')
>>> reader = csv.reader(f)
>>> headers = reader.next()
>>> headers
['workers', 'constant', 'age']
>>> column = {}
>>> for h in headers:
...    column[h] = []
...
>>> column
{'workers': [], 'constant': [], 'age': []}
>>> for row in reader:
...   for h, v in zip(headers, row):
...     column[h].append(v)
...
>>> column
{'workers': ['w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3'], 'constant': ['7.334', '5.235', '3.2225', '0'], 'age': ['-1.406', '-4.936', '-1.478', '0']}
>>> column['workers']
['w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3']
>>> column['constant']
['7.334', '5.235', '3.2225', '0']
>>> column['age']
['-1.406', '-4.936', '-1.478', '0']
>>>
```

You can get headers with .next() function and then you can iterate over the rows to get the values in the subsequent rows.

Comment: Thank you, @shwetabh-sharan. The answer ended up being in the request for additional information. After opening up the test CSV file to scrub the data and re-saving it under a new name before posting, I was able to read the column header line from the scrubbed CSV file.